# How to render text in OpenGL menu-system smartly?

Tags: c++, opengl, menu, text-rendering

I want to make a simple windowing system in an OpenGL app. Rendering menus with text-boxes, buttons, check-boxes, etc. How do I render this smartly?

So far I have 2 ideas:

- In each frame I render every character of the menu to the screen.
- I keep the menu/window in a texture, and render only this texture each frame. (and only update the parts of the texture that have changed.)

What are the downsides of each?

Comment: Both have its pro's and con's. Is it really easier for you to leave this decision to somebody else? Why not making sample implementations for both and checking afterwards which you like more? ("like" may, of course, involve performance measurement but I doubt that performance is the issue in this case. Actually, we speak about a few quads in either case...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the first bullet, then maybe implement the second bullet later as an optimization. The second bullet is sometimes known as "framebuffer caching". Note that Dear ImGui (a very popular GUI library that can use OpenGL for rendering) does not bother with framebuffer caching.

If you decide to implement framebuffer caching, the work you did in the beginning will not be wasted, since you will use it to update the cache.